# PHP Triggering two if statements in one line

Tags: php

I am struggling with two if statements that validate two input fields and display error messages below them in ONE row. I used two if statements but soon as I enter one input field the other error text message gone. I tried to use if, else statement but unfortunately it was only displaying one error messages instead of two.  Here is my code snippet

```
if ($fname == '') :     
$err_name = '<div class="error1">Please enter your first name</div>'; endif; 
if ($sname == '') :     
$err_sname = '<div class="error3">Please enter your surname</div>'; endif;
```

and here is the body of my html code...

```
<span class=="error"><span>
<label for="Firstname" class="label">First Name:</label>                                <input name="Firstname" id="Firstname" onfocus="form; clrfirst()" placeholder="Letters only" type="text" size="20" value = "<?php if (isset($fname)){ echo $fname; } ?>" /><!-- first name input field -->
<label for="Surname" class="surname">Surname:</label>
<input name="Surname" id="Surname" onfocus="form; clrsurname()" placeholder="Letters only"  type="text"  size="20" value = "<?php if (isset($sname)){ echo $sname; } ?>" />
```

and now the most important staff

```
<?php if (isset($err_sname)) {echo $err_sname; }  ?><?php if (isset($err_name)) {echo $err_name; }  ?>
 </div>
```

I hope  there must be a simple solution  for this but I dont know the PHP syntax so well. Any help is welcome !

Comment: Try: `if ( ! ($fname && $sname)) {...}`

Comment: Still I can't figure out how to display two messages in one row I tried something like this - "<?php if (isset($err_sname) && (isset($err_fname))) echo $err_sname; echo $err_fname   ?>" but then error comes up - Notice: Undefined variable: err_fname in C:\xampp\htdocs\enquiry.html.php on line 95

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&&` [operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) to check for both conditions

```
<?php
 if ($err_sname === '' && $err_fname === ''){
    // Continue here
  }

?>
```

Comment: also, try and isolate your comparisons e.g if(($err_sname === "") && ($err_fname === "")){ //do shtuff; }

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience, its always good to accumulate the errors and messages in a list and echo them whenever required. This way, you can also pass them between different classes and functions.

```
<?php

 $err = array();

 if ( empty($fname) ) {
      $err[] = '<div class="error1">Please enter your first name</div>';
 }
 if ( empty($sname) ) {
      $err[] = '<div class="error3">Please enter your surname</div>';
 }

 foreach( $err as $e ) {
      echo $e;
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<?php
  // This assumes that $fname and $sname are at least defined at some point
  if ($fname == '' || $sname == '') :   
    // If $fname is set but equal to '', then '<div class="error1">..</div>', otherwise FALSE  
    $err_name = (isset($fname) && $fname == '') ? '<div class="error1">Please enter your first name</div>' : FALSE; 
    //  If $sname is set but equal to '', then '<div class="error3">..</div>', otherwise FALSE  
    $err_sname = (isset($sname) && $sname == '') ? '<div class="error3">Please enter your surname</div>' : FALSE;
  endif;
```